# 7-Letter word; starts with X; contains one vowel; letters can be repeated

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many 7-letter words can I form, starting with X, containing one and only one vowel, and considering letters can be repeated?

How do I solve this using counting and/or permutations?

I saw an answer for this but there were $ signs and I was not able to understand it.

Comment: Solve what? You haven't asked a question. Do you want a count of such words? Is it exactly one vowel, or possibly more?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough! How many 7-letter words can I form based on those criteria? And only one vowel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $X$ at the beginning is fixed, and letters can be repeated, so we can just ignore it.

The vowel can be in one of $6$ places and there are $5$ possible vowels. The other $5$ letters can each be one of the $21$ consonants.

So in total there are $6\cdot 5 \cdot 21^5=122523030$ such words.

EDIT:

If the letters can't be repeated, consider the $5$ remaining letters:

The first one can be one of $20$ letters (not an $X$, not a vowel).
The second one can be one of $19$ letters (same as first, but can't equal the first either). etc.

So there are $6\cdot 5\cdot 20\cdot19\cdot 18\cdot 17\cdot 16=55814400$ words.

Comment: What if letters cannot be repeated?

Comment: @user276520 I edited my answer for the non-repeated case.

Comment: Everything's clear now. Thank you very much Alex!

Comment: @user276520 You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here is the "fundamental theorem of counting": if event A can happen in m ways and, for each of those, event B can happen in n ways, then both events can happen in mn ways.

Since the first letter **must** be X, it is just the 6 succeeding letters that can be changed.  There are 5 vowels so, assuming we put the vowel as the second letter, there are 5 choices.  There are 21 "non-vowels" so there 21 choices for the last 5.  The number of possibilities for X, vowel, and then 5 non-vowels is 5(21)(21)(21)(21)(21)= 5(21^5).  But we could have the same letters with the vowel in any of the six places following X so we must multiply that by 6: 5(6)(21^5).

(This is assuming that "contains one vowel" means "contains exactly one vowel".)